# Generic programming with concepts clashing with copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, concept

I'm trying to use a generic coding style to wrap a restricted concept API over generic stacks.
The problem I'm running into is that one of my constructors, the most important one that takes a templatised stack, is overriding my copy constructor.
I have a gist with the class in question, some test code, and the error I get from the compiler here: https://gist.github.com/biot023/5178831

I want to be able to use value semantics with the stacks I create, which I can when just assigning to a vector of them. However, this is giving me my copy constructor issue.

Could anyone advise how I could maybe explicitly trigger the copy constructor (which I only really need to do in my test code), or maybe show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `__stack` is a reserved name. Don't use double underscores, or names starting with underscore in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your constructor template is a better match than your copy constructor:

```
// Copy constructor
WrappedStack( const WrappedStack &other )

// Constructor template
template <typename S>
WrappedStack( S &stack )
```

When instantiated with an object of type `WrappedStack<T>` (where `T` is the *class* template parameter), the instantiated signature of the constructor template will look like:

```
WrappedStack( WrappedStack<T> &stack )
```

This is better match than the copy constructor if the type of the argument is not `const`-qualified, because it does not require a `const` conversion. Therefore, the constructor template will be picked by overload resolution, and its body will be instantiated, causing the error you are experiencing.

To force the compiler to use the copy constructor when appropriate, you could use SFINAE to cause a substitution failure when instantiating the constructor template with an object of type `WrappedStack<T>`, or of a type which is implicitly convertible to `WrappedStack<T>`. For instance:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<
    typename S,
    typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_convertible<S, WrappedStack<T> const&>::value
        >::type* = nullptr>
WrappedStack( S &stack ) : __stack( new wrapped_stack_t<S, T>( stack ) ) {}
```

See a live example of this [succesfully compiling](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4cvdpz%2453).

Comment: `!std::is_convertable<S, WrappedStack<T> const&>::value` instead of `is_same` inside that `enable_if` is a way to make your template constructor always give way to your `WrappedStack<T> const&` constructor.

Comment: Looks like I have some rather useful reading to do on SFINAE and enable_if -- thanks very much for that! And the live work space is really interesting, too, thankyou.

Comment: Thanks again for that, it is working nicely. I've been doing a bit of reading, but don't understand why your template declaration works, whereas the one I hacked together whilst researching didn't. Mine was:

`template <
          typename S,
          typename std::enable_if<! std::is_convertible<S, const WrappedStack<T> &>::value>::type
        >`

I'll keep thinking on it, but thought I'd ask in case I'm missing something pretty obvious.